# Data Extraction DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a file in the below format called BAIMTHP in our library.

I want to extract the lines related 50K only (For TEF_NO 12345, ROW_# 3, 4 & 5 For TEF_NO 56789, ROW_# 1, 2, 3 & 4). Issue is that the TAG field will not be populated for all rows, instead, the ROW_# will be populating. I tried the below SQL but I was able to extract only the 1st row of the TAG field. In this case ROW_# 1 and 3 only (For TEF_NO=56789 & TEF_NO=12345, respectively).

Is there a way to do this in DB2? TAG 50K will populate only in maximum of 4 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP. TEST AS (SELECT * FROM EMOQRYLIB.BAIMTHP WHERE TAG = '50K')
```

Since images are not allowed to upload for my profile, I had to type the sample file details

```
TEF_NO     TAG           ROW_#     TEXT 
12345         20K          1                XXXXXX
12345         25K          2               XXXXXX
12345         50K          3               29/1
12345                          4              Ahamath Lane
12345                          5              Colombo
56789         50K          1              No 11
56789                          2             17th Lane
56789                          3             Colpitty
56789                          4             Colombo
56789          57A          5             XXXXXX
56789          52B          6             XXXXXX
```

**IDEAL OUTPUT**

```
TEF_NO     TAG           ROW_#     TEXT 
12345         50K          3               29/1
12345                          4              Ahamath Lane
12345                          5              Colombo
56789         50K          1              No 11
56789                          2             17th Lane
56789                          3             Colpitty
56789                          4             Colombo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear about the logic - if the TAG field is null only after a 50K row - but following SQL would do the job (using table name t50 in my case):

```
select tef_no, tag, row_#, text
  from t50 t
 where tef_no in (select tef_no  from t50  where tag = '50K' )
   and row_# >= (select row_#  from t50  where tag = '50K' and  tef_no= t.tef_no)
   and row_# < (select row_#  from t50  where tag = '50K' and  tef_no= t.tef_no) + 4
```